# Magento Migration steps in details

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, migration

I have tried migrating M1 with sample data & rwd theme to M2 luma theme & data from M1, which worked & now wanna migrate M1(real live site data) with extension(its data) & its theme to M2 & bit of confused to plan it, like what should I do first.

1. Install latest M2 without sample data
2. Migrate M1 data to M2
3. Install/configure M2 paid/3rd party theme & paid/3rd party extension

or

1. Install latest M2 without sample data
2. Install/configure M2 paid/3rd party theme & paid/3rd party extension
3. Migrate M1 data to M2

What should I do? As I dont want to loose any data added to magento1 tables(ie. in sales_flat_order_grid , sales rules, catalog_product_flat, etc) by extension & so I am assuming If I install M2 extension & then migrate data all extension data will be added to magento tables(some of mentioned above)

And after migration of category, products, customers & sales
How can I again migrate all data(from beginning of 1st record) for **just only customer & sales**? **without delta migration**

Answer (score 0):

I prefer second option. i.e.

1. Install latest M2 without sample data
2. Install/configure M2 paid/3rd party theme & paid/3rd party extension
3. Migrate M1 data to M2

You can utilize Magento data migration tool from [Magento](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool) or from [Uber](https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-extensions-2-x/magento-2-data-migration-pro/) and its expected that there will be certain manual ETL to be done for the customer theme and modules data to fit together in the latest versions of 3rd party theme and extensions.

For Uber, the steps of migration are stored in sqlite DB and you can modify the steps to run and pause from the sqlite DB itself.

Specially, you can migrate followings:

1. Product Catalog
2. Customer Accounts without password/credentials
3. SalesOrder Data without vault info.
4. Gift Card/Coupons/Vouchers with custom ETL
5. Blog: there is no blog in magento 2, hence you can't migrate this.
6. List item

Answer (score 0):

The steps you mentioned here are very helpful. But some Magento eCommerce owners find it difficult to do the migration thing by themselves.

And it becomes a necessity for them to take the help of a Magento development company.

It may be difficult for these store owners to calculate the cost of this migration
and which factors are considered while calculating the Magento 2 Migration Cost.

This [Magento 2 Migration cost guide](https://webdesksolution.com/blog/magento-2-migration-cost/) can help them to understand all the cost factors and costs of migration.